# NSDictionary FBGraphUser Swift translation

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I stumbled upon this piece of Objective-C code:

```
- (void)updateUser:(NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)user inSlot:(NSInteger)slot {
[self validateSlotNumber:slot];

NSString *idKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:SUUserIDKeyFormat, (long)slot];
NSString *nameKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:SUUserNameKeyFormat, (long)slot];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (user != nil) {
NSLog(@"SUUserManager updating slot %li: fbid = %@, name = %@", (long)slot, user.objectID, user.name);
[defaults setObject:user.objectID forKey:idKey];
[defaults setObject:user.name forKey:nameKey];
} else {
NSLog(@"SUUserManager clearing slot %li", (long)slot);

// Can't be current user anymore
if (slot == _currentUserSlot) {
[self switchToNoActiveUser];
}

// FBSample logic
// Also need to tell the token cache to forget the tokens for this user
FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy *tokenCachingStrategy = [self createCachingStrategyForSlot:slot];
[tokenCachingStrategy clearToken];

[defaults removeObjectForKey:idKey];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:nameKey];
}

[defaults synchronize];

[self sendNotification];
}
```

It is from one of the Facebook iOS SDK examples. I am trying to use it in my Swift written app. This is what I come up with:

```
func updateUser(user: Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>, slot: Int) {
    var idKey: String = String(format: userIDKeyFormat, slot)
    var nameKey: String = String(format: userNameKeyFormat, slot)
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if(user != nil) {
        println("UserManager updating slot \(slot): Facebook ID = \(user.objectID), Name = \(user.name)")
        defaults.setObject(user.objectID, forKey: idKey)
        defaults.setObject(user.name, forKey: nameKey)
    } else {
        println("UserManager clearing slot \(slot)")

        if(slot == currentUserSlot) {
            self.switchToNoActiveUser()
        }

        var tokenCachingStrategy: FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy = self.createCachingStrategyForSlot(slot)

        tokenCachingStrategy.clearToken()
        defaults.removeObjectForKey(idKey)
        defaults.removeObjectForKey(nameKey)
    }
    defaults.synchronize()
    self.sendNotification()
}
```

The problem is in `Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>` which, I think, is just not the same as the Obj-C equivalent. In the if statement to check if `user` is not nil, Xcode throws an error: 'Dictionary' is not convertible to 'String'.

So how do I translate the Obj-C code to Swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive research I finally found a way:

```
func updateUser<val: NSDictionary where val:protocol<FBGraphUser>>(user:val!, slot: Int) {

    var idKey: String = String(format: userIDKeyFormat, slot)
    var nameKey: String = String(format: userNameKeyFormat, slot)
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if(user != nil) {
        println("UserManager updating slot \(slot): Facebook ID = \(user!.objectID), Name = \(user!.name)")
        defaults.setObject(user!.objectID, forKey: idKey)
        defaults.setObject(user!.name, forKey: nameKey)
    } else {
        println("UserManager clearing slot \(slot)")

        if(slot == currentUserSlot) {
            self.switchToNoActiveUser()
        }

        var tokenCachingStrategy: FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy = self.createCachingStrategyForSlot(slot)

        tokenCachingStrategy.clearToken()
        defaults.removeObjectForKey(idKey)
        defaults.removeObjectForKey(nameKey)
    }
    defaults.synchronize()
    self.sendNotification()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set you dictionary as an optional:

```
func updateUser(user: Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>?, slot: Int) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but it give me the following error: 'Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>?' does not have a member named 'objectID' Also for user.name. With other words, it does not see user as a graph user? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: yes i think you have to force the unwrapping of the optional and check if it was successful if var unwrapped_user = user as FBGraphUser { ...do you stuff but use the unwrapped_user }

Comment: This optionals subject is bugging me. I tried your advice: `if var unwrappedUser = user as FBGraphUser {
            
        }`  but it is giving me this error: `Cannot downcast from 'Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>?' to non-@objc protocol type 'FBGraphUser'`

Comment: I got it working with this `func updateUser<val: NSDictionary where val:protocol<FBGraphUser>>(user:val!, slot: Int) { }` Thanks for helping me out!